# Ganache hash doesn't match Web3j response with error `TxHashMismatchException`

Tags: ethereum, web3-java

When trying to run any transaction using Web3j on Ganache it fails with the exception: `TxHashMismatchException`.
It seems that something has changed on Ganache that is breaking the interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Ganache has changed the way the transactions hashes are created since version 6.2.0. This problem doesn't exist on version `v6.1.8` and earlier, using `v6.1.8` should fix your issue.

If you are running Ganache using Docker make sure that you specify the version and not `latest`.